# How to add an event to a div container that will copy the content of that container and send it to another div container

Tags: react-hooks, onclick, state, react-props

I am working on a booking website in react, and I want to add a click event to the service div, so that whenever I click on any service I want to book, it will automatically copy the content in the service div and send it to another div container that shows the services I have booked, in a list form. Then I want to add the prices in the new container and display it in the "total section "

`the codes`

```
    import "./about.css";
    import "./about-     responsive.css";
    import AboutImg from "../Images/service-1.png";


    const About = () => {

    return (
        <>
            <section className="about">
                <div className="about-contain">
                    <div className="about-txt">
                              <h2>About</h2>
                            <p>Located in the beautiful San Francisco area,
                            Spalax specializes in first-class restorative
                            treatments. We aim to nurture and relax each
                            of our guests with individualized and innovative
                            therapeutic techniques. Creating a safe place for
                            healing to occur, we use natural and pure ingredients
                            to nourish your body and soul. Schedule your next
                            visit in a place where your well-being is top priority.</p>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div className="about-img">
                    <img src={AboutImg} alt="" />
                </div>

            </section>


            <section className="container-mssg">

                <div className="send-msg">
                    <h6>Send Us a Message</h6>
                    <form action="POST" className="contact">
                        <input type="text" name="Name" id="text" className="input" placeholder="Enter Name" required />
                        <input type="email" name="Email" id="email" className="input" placeholder="Email" required />
                        <textarea name="Message" id="message" cols="1" rows="3" placeholder="Input message" required></textarea>
                            <button>Send</button>
                        <p>.   <b>Note:</b> *Our services only convers people in [USA, UK and Canada]. Remember Your satisfactio is my priority and as your personnal home erotic massage therapist, i am here to carter to your every decision. Let me take you on a sensual adventure unike any other.</p>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </section >


            <script src="../About/faq.js"></script>
        </>
    );
}

export default About;
```

[Website render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2Whm.jpg)

[Codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pU9O.jpg)

[Codes continuation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAeMq.jpg)